# Why did this hashmap stop working out of no where?

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I have used this HashMap for a few days now and no problems at all. Now I get an error about FloatingDecimal,parseDouble, ReadWrite, FileReadWrite, and Looping error.

the last thing I did to the program was adding $%.2f.formant to my ducts.second element it ran a few times I left to eat and came back to this!

I was able to narrow it down to when it pulls the data from the file and converts it to the hashmap setting.

Data in the file example 111,shoes,59.00

```
  val fileName = "src/products.txt"
    var products = HashMap<Int, Pair<String, Double>>()

    var inputFD =File(fileName).forEachLine {
        var pieces = it.split(",")
        // println(pieces)
        products [pieces [0].toInt()] = Pair(pieces [1].trim(),pieces[2].toDouble())
    }
```

Comment: Apparently, your input data is in the wrong format. Without seeing what that data actually looks like, it's hard to provide suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: I just figured it out!! Thank you! When I looked at the file I didn't think about the $59,99 vs 59.99. I accidentally sent it back to the file adding the $ .

Answer (score 0):

The data type in the file was altered when reading back in causing the whole program to crash. I wanted my double to be example 9.99 and when I read the file back in I added a $ sign meant for the front in view only. When the program was looking for a double (9.99) is only had the option of ($9.99) causing the error.